# Update root scope from an AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive, which watches for a inout box for old and new value. I would want to update the rootscope value here "total" . I tried to use all, that I knew like $rootScope, broadcast the message, emit the message. Here is the code.

```
app.directive('costCheck',function($compile,$rootScope,$timeout){
$rootScope.gName= "What did i buy?";
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope,element,attrs){                    
            attrs.$observe('costCheck',function(value){ 

            });
            scope.$watch('cost',function(oldval,newval){alert(attrs.name);  
                alert(oldval+'--'+newval);
                var message = {type: 'channel', action: 'create', data: { name: "ssss", id: 0}};      
                $rootScope.$broadcast('get',message); 
            });     
        }
    }
});
```

This is my main controller

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope) {
 $scope.totalCost = 'workinggg';
 $rootScope.$on('go', function() {alert();
        $scope.totalCost = 'working';
    });
});
```

How to update the rootscope.

Comment: You're listening to `go` and broadcasting `get`.

Comment: If you only want to update the value you can pass it to the scope `scope : { value : '=value'}` and avoid nasty `broadcast`/`emit`s.

Comment: I forgot to tell this in my question, the directive belongs below another controller

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comment from @haki that you should bind the scope values from the controller/directive as shown.

```
scope : { value : '=value'}
```

But if you are wanting to broadcast for other reasons (i.e. other controllers) then change $rootScope.$on to $scope.$on. $scope is a child of $rootScope and the broadcast sends the message down to child scopes.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T8v6t/) showing the binding to the directive scope working.

**Edit:** [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T8v6t/1/) update to set totalCost on $rootScope in the directive

**Edit 2:** [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T8v6t/3/) update to broadcast value down from $rootScope, and handled in another controller

Comment: I did not get you!, i tried doing this in ym directive but no luck!

Comment: @user3498603 I added a fiddle to explain the binding between the controller and the directive

Comment: This doesn't work for me, since the directive belongs to a different controller and with that I have to update the rootscope value.

Comment: I updated the fiddle to set $rootScope.totalCost directly inside the directive.

Comment: The 2nd fiddle IS updating $rootScope.totalCost which you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/T8v6t/2/ as the second binding in the h1 is outside of the controller. What error are you seeing?

Comment: Actually I don't see any error, {{totalCost}} belongs to a different controller and the directive is from different controller attribute.

Comment: Added another fiddle that shows the value being caught/set in another controller.

Comment: broadcast is not working, I tried it even before posting it. I can past my code if you want. The html is appended to the dom and injector is used to bind the events. May be thats the reason its not working

Comment: You'll have to do that. I don't think I can do anymore to the examples I posted.

Comment: no problem, I am trying..thank you!
i shall post if i solve that :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish this, and I wouldn't do it this way, but I'm just trying to make your code work here.

- I guess you don't want to update the root scope (as the title says), but you want to communicate through the root scope.
- As @Shomz said, you need to match the event names of course.
- If you use $rootScope, you can just emit the event instead of doing a broadcast, then it doesn't have to bubble down in your app

Directive code:

```
$rootScope.$emit('totalCostUpdated',message);
```

Main controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope) {
   $scope.totalCost = 'workinggg';
   $rootScope.$on('totalCostUpdated', function(event, args) {
       $scope.totalCost = 'working';
   });
});
```

I would probably do it with a shared service, though. Take a look at https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-sharing-data-between-controllers .